# Derivative of Gaussian

Tags: differentiation, mathematics

I have this variational problem where i want to find the derivative of a Gaussian. In matrix notation the problem looks like this (with the solution on the right)
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}} A \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}}} \left( \exp \left( \frac{1}{4} \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}} B^{-1} \mathbf{x} \right)  \right) = 
\left( \frac{3}{2} \mathrm{tr} (AB^{-1}) + \mathbf{y}^{\mathbf{T}}A\mathbf{y}  \right)\exp \left( \frac{1}{4} \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}} B^{-1} \mathbf{x} \right), $$
$A$ and $B^{-1}$ are both symmetric positive definite matrices, $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector of vectors $\vec{x}_i$ and $ \mathbf{y}=\frac{1}{2}  B^{-1} \mathbf{x} $.

My attempt at a solution thus far has been
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}}} \left( \exp \left( \frac{1}{4} \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}} B^{-1} \mathbf{x} \right)  \right) = \mathbf{y} \exp \left( \frac{1}{4} \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}} B^{-1} \mathbf{x} \right)
$$
and then
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}} A \left( \mathbf{y} \exp \left( \frac{1}{4} \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}} B^{-1} \mathbf{x} \right)  \right) =  \left(
 \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}} \left( A B^{-1} \mathbf{x} \right) + \mathbf{y}^{\mathbf{T}}A\mathbf{y} \right) \exp \left( \frac{1}{4} \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}} B^{-1} \mathbf{x} \right),
$$
using the product rule and that the matrices $B^{-1}$ and $A$ are symmetric. But i cannot figure out how the $\frac{3}{2} \mathrm{tr}(A B^{-1})$ comes to be. I know there is a trace trick where $ \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}} A \mathbf{x} = \mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}} A \mathbf{x}) $, but it seems to me that it cannot be applied here.

Any suggestions, hints or help would be appreciated.

Comment: I voted to migrate this to Math.SE